# populate flet datatable with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datatable, row, flet

how can I disable pandas dataframe in flet datatable and be able to edit and delete each row.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 |

I tried setting the column headers by calling

```
df.column
```

but I don't know how to go about populating the row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've taken the code from another answer and reworked it quite a bit. I'm not sure if I'm unpacking the pandas dataframe in the most efficient way. Maybe someone with more experience can add to this.

```
import flet as ft
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
        "test" : ['1', "20", "40"],
        "test1" : ['2', "21", "41"],
        "test2" : ['3', "22", "43"],
    })


def headers(df : pd.DataFrame) -> list:
    return [ft.DataColumn(ft.Text(header)) for header in df.columns]

def rows(df : pd.DataFrame) -> list:
    rows = []
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        rows.append(ft.DataRow(cells = [ft.DataCell(ft.Text(row[header])) for header in df.columns]))
    return rows

            
def main(page ft.Page):
    datatable = ft.DataTable(
        columns=headers(df),
        rows=rows(df))
    
    page.add(datatable)

ft.app(target=main)
```

Answer (score 0):

like this build DataTable from DataFrame

```
datatable = ft.DataTable()

for i in range(len(df.columns)):
     datatable.columns.append(ft.DataColumn(ft.Text(df.columns[i])))
     for x in range(len(df['name'])):
           datatable.rows.append(
                ft.DataRow(
                 cells=[
                 ft.DataCell(ft.Text(df["name"][x])), 
                 ft.DataCell(ft.Text(df["age"][x])),
                 ]
                 ) 
           )
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).